# XamarinForms CollectionView: is it possible to assign x:DataType from a different assembly?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm

I am a beginner with Xamarin.Forms. In my first project (more or less copied from the VS 2019 template 'Flyout') I have a collection of items defined in a view model. The elements of the collection are instances of a class defined in a different assembly.
In the definition of the CollectionView the following has been added:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
xmlns:model1="clr-namespace:MyLibrary.Domain;assembly=MyLibrary"
```

(MyLibrary is in an assembly different from that in which ViewModels are).
When I now try to define ItemSource and x:DataType for the CollectionView, there arises a problem: either I can define the ItemSource (from xmlns:local) or the DataType (from xmlns:model1), but not both. Is it generally possible to have the element class from a different assembly? And if yes (which I hope), how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is you are trying to use compiled bindings, so basically to apply your complied binding to your CollectionView you just need to apply it to your page,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<local:BaseContentPage
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
xmlns:model1="clr-namespace:MyLibrary.Domain;assembly=MyLibrary"
x:DataType="local:BaseViewModel"
```

And to apply it to the CollectionView you apply it to the `DataTemplate`, not to the CollectionView

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="model1:BaseModel">
```

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings#use-compiled-bindings-in-a-datatemplate), Goodluck feel free to get back in case of queries

Comment: Many thanks @FreakyAli! It worked like by charm!

Comment: VS 2019 even automatically inserts
<!--
    x:DataType enables compiled bindings for better performance and compile time validation of binding expressions.
    https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings
  -->
somewhere before CollectionView, but I naturally neglected it.

Comment: Happy to help, Please mark it as correct if it solves your issue